# Win7 x64 Taskbar: Add Icon for Specific Tab in Mouse Properties?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, taskbar, touchpad

The touchpad on my laptop is OK when I need it, but I like to turn it off when I'm using the mouse. To do this, I go into Control Panel > Mouse > UltraNav tab > uncheck Enable TouchPad. I'd prefer to make that just one step: pin an icon to the taskbar, and click on it to uncheck Enable TouchPad.

I can probably figure out the way to iconize a program (e.g., a batch file) that would run the command or registry edit to make this change. But I don't know what the command or registry edit is.

Comment: I think the closest built in command is to run `main.cpl` to open "Mouse Properties". You can probably write a script to get closer to what you actually want.

Comment: I guess that's what I don't know how to do. When I have the UltraNav tab open, Windows Task Manager tells me I'm running C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe. But it says that for all tabs in Mouse Properties. I know how to write batch files, but I don't exactly know what the batch file should do.